# FTP uploading error

Tags: c#, file, ftp

I'm working on an ftp application in c# in which I have to download a file and upload the same file. here is my code for download data.

```
try
{
    textBox1.Text = ftpServerIP;
    textBox2.Text = ftpUserID;
    textBox3.Text = ftpPassword;
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    //filePath = <<The full path where the file is to be created.>>, 
    //fileName = <<Name of the file to be created(Need not be the name of the file on FTP server).>>
    FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
    Uri downloadPath = new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + client_fileName);
    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(downloadPath);
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
    Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    long cl = response.ContentLength;
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int readCount;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (readCount > 0)
    {
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    ftpStream.Close();
    outputStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    DataBaseOperations db = new DataBaseOperations();
    templist = db.GetData();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = templist;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

and my uploading function is

```
public void Upload(string filename, string url)
{
    FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filename+"\\test.s3db");
    string uri = "ftp://" + url + "/" +"/public_html/RemoteDic/" + " test.s3db";
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;
    FileStream inputStream = fileInf.OpenRead();
    using (var outputStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        int totalReadBytesCount = 0;
        int readBytesCount;
        while ((readBytesCount = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytesCount);
            totalReadBytesCount += readBytesCount;
            var progress = totalReadBytesCount * 100.0 / inputStream.Length;
        }
        outputStream.Close();
    }
    inputStream.Close();
}
```

When I run the program I get an error

> The process cannot access the file `'E:\rafay zia mir\web connect\web connect\bin\Debug\test.s3db'` because it is being used by another process.

But in the downloading section all streams are closed after the file has been downloaded.

Comment: Is another program using the file? Try using process explorer to see where the handle is.

Comment: i have checked many times no program is using that database file.
"Try using process explorer to see where the handle is". cant get that.can u explain a little bit?

Comment: If there is something on your computer that has this file open that you can't see open or in task mananger you can do a search in process explorer to clarify whether there really is another process using the file.